Is it possible to access a constant (ex. BuildConfigField), defined in app/build.gradle, in a custom local Expo module?
I have a React Native app createad with Expo. I am trying to create a custom native module using Expo Module API that can access the BuildConfig variables defined with BuildConfigField in app/build.gradle for Android and eventually use them in the JavaScript layer.
What I've done so far is:

In /app/build.config add this line somewhere at the end of the android block:

buildConfigField "String", "TEST", '"THIS_IS_A_TEST"'


Create a local native module using npx create-expo-module@latest --local with name: my-module

This creates a directory modules/ with my-module inside that contains the android and ios directories with the native code.
If we focus entirely on the Android part, this is what /modules/my-module/android/src/main/java/bg/example/MyModule.kt looks like:
package bg.example

import bg.example.android.BuildConfig
import expo.modules.kotlin.modules.Module
import expo.modules.kotlin.modules.ModuleDefinition

class BuildConfigModule : Module() {
  override fun definition() = ModuleDefinition {
    Name("BuildConfig")
    
    Function("doSomethingWithBuildConfigField") {
      return@Function BuildConfig.TEST
    }
  }
}


In /modules/my-module/index.ts I export the defined function:

import MyModule from './src/MyModule';

export function doSomethingWithBuildConfigField(): string {
  return MyModule.doSomethingWithBuildConfigField();
}

So when I try to build the app I get an error: Unresolved reference: TEST
It seams that I can only access BuildConfig.DEBUG, BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE and BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME.
I guess the custom module is build independently from the other native code, and thus, does not know about what I define in app/build.gradle.
So, how can I access this BuildConfig variables in my custom native module? Is this even possible? Is there some other way to define a variable in build.gradle (maybe using resValue) and access this instead?
